# API response returns JSON without Response Body

Tags: php, json, laravel, request, guzzle

Using Guzzle, I'm consuming some external apis in JSON format,
usually I get the data with

$data = $request->getBody()->getContents();

But i can't get data from this different api.
It seems the data doesn't come in a 'Response Body'.

This api call works:
https://i.ibb.co/80Yk6dx/Screenshot-2.png

This doesn't work:
https://i.ibb.co/C239ghy/Screenshot-3.png

```
public function getRemoteCienciaVitaeDistinctions()
{
    $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);

    $request = $client->get(
        'https://................/',
        [
            'auth'          => ['...', '...'],
        ]

    );

    $data = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete, what library are  you using ? is it guzzle ?

Comment: yes sorry, is Guzzle.

Comment: what this is returns: `$request->getBody()->getContents()` and what should actually return ?

Comment: it returns an empty string and it should return a json with data

Comment: try this to check whether your code is working `https://reqres.in/api/products/3`
this is return sample json code. remove your auth

Comment: yeah it works.
it works also with many other api methods from the same source, but there are a few that i cant get the info.

Comment: what is the name of this api?

Answer (score 0):

the second call is working fine, but the response is empty, 
as we can see in Screenshot-3, the `Total  = 0`, so the response from this API is empty.

to handle that properly I suggest you this modification for your method :

```
public function getRemoteCienciaVitaeDistinctions()
{
    $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);

    $request = $client->get(
        'https://................/',
        [
            'auth'          => ['...', '...'],
        ]

    );

    //Notice that i have decoded the response from json objects to php array here.

    $response = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents());

    if(isset($response->total) && $response->total == 0) return [];

    return $response;
}
```

please check the documentation of the API that you are using